# How to add method fields to ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the DRF documentation for SerializerMethodField it gives the following usage example

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

Unfortunately it fails in the latest release of DRF because ModelSerializer expects either `fields` or `exclude` to be present in the Meta. This presents a problem. If I list the method field in the `fields` list, I get an error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `days_since_joined` is not valid for model `User`.
```

And if I do not include the method field or if I use `fields = "__all__"` or if I use `exclude` the method field ends up missing in the serialized data.

How do I include the method field in a model serializer?

**Edit:** I have found an ugly hack that allows adding method fields for custom models. You can add a fake property to the model and then everything works as expected.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.IntegerField()
    field2 = models.CharField()
    # more fields

    @property
    def my_method_field(self):
        return None

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_method_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='bleh')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'my_method_field')

    def bleh(self, obj):
        return 'Bleh!'
```

But adding placeholder property code to models for something like this is not a good practice and this does not solve the problem of doing this with externally defined models such as Django User model.

**Edit #2** I would swear that I have tried adding every possible combination of exclude and fields. Yet somehow when I returned to the problem the next day, it just worked with a reasonable exclude. I will mark the "empty exclude" answer as the right one and leave this here as a tribute to fickleness of human attention and the secret magic of gremlins.

Comment: Could you confirm if you are getting `days_since_joined` is not present or `date_joined` is not?

Comment: Things to check are correct: 

- Method name is in Meta.fields (let's say it's "foo")
- Don't forget to add a "foo" SerializerMethodField property
- For the method itself - make sure it's get_foo and not just foo. Don't make method_name='foo' and def foo (you can't have the same name). You can use method_name but make sure it's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try empty `exclude`?

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ()
        #       ^^^^^

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```